# Who decides which countries are third world and how can it be challenged?

Tags: united-nations

South Africa has become exceptionally powerful and its infrastructure has grown into what I'd regard as a First World country.

I'd like to challenge its third world status.

How does one go about this.

Is there a formal process or is the First World / Third World thing simply a casual term thrown around by politicians since the Cold War?

Comment: Consider that [some look at impoverishment as being the qualifier for 'third world' living](http://aidwatchers.com/2011/02/third-world-america/), not national GDP / etc.

Comment: [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_world_country), wikipedia **already** considers south africa to be a first world country

Comment: Keep in mind that [Third World](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/third_world.htm) had an older definition, "The term Third World was originally coined in times of the Cold War to distinguish those nations that are neither aligned with the West (NATO) nor with the East, the Communist bloc. Today the term is often used to describe the developing countries of Africa, Asia, Latin America and Oceania." words change, by using them in a different context and get a large number of people to adopt it. (I.e. **liberal** in the USA, **(Anti-)federalist**, **spending in the tax code**)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did "third world" fall out of favor?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/606/why-did-third-world-fall-out-of-favor)

Answer (score 8):

Since Switzerland, Sweden, and Ireland were all considered third world countries by the original definition (not allied with either NATO or the Warsaw Pact), it's safe to say that first and third world country are not very rigidly defined. Even at the time, the original definition was pretty creaky since alliances were rarely explicit and the polar nature of Soviet vs US interests made cases like China after their break with the USSR hard to place.

Labeling countries as third world as shorthand for impoverished, or undeveloped stems from the US and Soviet tendency to use developing non-allied nations as battlefields in their proxy war (ie Vietnam, Afghanistan, Egypt) in order to avoid directly challenging each others' spheres of influence. Since the competition to expand influence in the "third world" ranged from bribery through foreign aid to overthrow by force, the contested countries naturally began to look largely the same to the general public- poor, war torn, and unstable.

So-- obsolete term with pejorative overtones that just needs to be retired altogether.